# How to use interactive US Map in Angular 2 or How to import and use an external javascript in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, raphael

I came across https://github.com/robflaherty/us-map-raphael and wanted to use this in Angular2 application.

In plain JS world, we can import lib and instantiate

```
<script>   window.onload = function () {
     var R = Raphael("container", 1000, 900) 
</script>
```

in Angular2 component based framework, Raphael being external JS lib, firstly, I tried to provide dependency in my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
           ...
           "raphael": "^2.2.7" }
```

However, am finding it difficult to import and create instance.

I tried to import

```
import * as raphaelJS from 'raphael/raphael.js';
...
ngOnInit() {
      let inst = raphaelJS.Raphael("container", 1000, 900);
...
```

But am getting "Cannot find module 'raphael/raphael.js'" error during compilation

Alternatively, I tried to declare a var:any and create instance, but it complained "Cannot find name 'Raphael'.)"

```
declare var jsVar: any;
...
ngOnInit() {
      jsVar = Raphael("container", 1000, 900);
```

1. May I know how I can use an external library in Angular2
2. To use interactive us-map in Angular2, may I know if there is any better solution

PS: I used ng-cli to generate project [its webpack based]

Appreciate any advise on this!

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it using svg tag and create my own interactive map you can view the plnkr in this link - Please view the code

```
<svg
  version="1.1"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 2000 800">
  <svg:path
    *ngFor="let country of countries; let i = index"
    [attr.data-index]="i"
    (mouseover)="countryHover = country.country_country"
    (click)="clicked(i)"
    class="blob"
    [class.selected]="hasCountry(i)"
    [attr.d]="country.country_path"
    fill="currentColor">
  </svg:path>
</svg>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lr5d2.jpg)

https://plnkr.co/edit/2heVmd7l4UokqR2OcNgm?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Raphael map library is one of the good sources for Map. It's very hard to manage external javascript source into Angular 2 as there are so many possibilities to change and missing events.

[angular us map](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-us-map) is one of the good source that complete your requirement. Using this package you can bind your own event to process further. i.e. by clicking on state.